# ¿Cómo saber desviación de clock source de Raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, time

La raspberry Pi no tiene un RTC (Real Time Clock) por lo que la hora que te da se calcula via software. ¿Cómo se puede calcular la desviación que tiene este clock source de la raspberry pi (e.g. ppm)?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que no podrás sincronizarla via nttp, así lo sabrías facilmente.

Existen módulos hardware para hacer lo que tu quieres. Al no tener pila, no puede guardar la hora:
[El primero módulo que he encontrado con google para que te hagas una idea](http://ingeniapp.com/configura-un-rtc-reloj-tiempo-real-en-tu-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: Claro, el problema es que es una conexión inalambrica y ntp no es muy estable a ese nivel. Otro problema de los RTC es que tienen precisión de segundos, no llega a milisegundos que es lo que me interesaría (o por lo menos no en los que yo he mirado y en este de microchip tamboién). El caso es que todos los relojes ya via HW o SW tienen un error de cálculo que suele darse en partes por millón (ppm). Sí supiera el ppm del clk calculado por SW podría saber cuan bueno es. Gracias por la respuesta de todas formas!